# Can I control my Sonos system?

Tags: 8.1

I have a Sonos system at home. Is there any way to control it using my Nokia Lumia with Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: You should badger Sonos about this, the more of us that do the more likely they are to bring out an official app.

Answer (score 1):

There's no official app, but the Store offers quite a lot of 3rd party apps for controlling Sonos systems. Since Sonos has many different hardware systems and the setup possibilities are endless, you should try the free and trial app versions first if they suit your requirements.

Comment: What third-party apps are available?

Comment: Depends ... the offers are market specific, so your mileage may vary. For me Phonos does a great job. If you don't have a multi-room setup, any UPnP or DLNA app will do. Simply search for sonos, dlna, upnp in your Store app.